# Can't get GATT characteristics C# Unable to cast BluetoothLEDevice to IBluetoothLEDevice3

Tags: c#, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, windowsiot

I'm a newbie in Bluetooth LE programming. I've already built the program I'm working on for Android, and now I'm trying to port it to C# / Windows IoT.

I'm trying to read Health Thermometer data sent in a BLE Advertisement package. Each time I try to access the device's GATT services, my code throws an exception:

```
private TypedEventHandler<BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs> OnAdvertisementReceived = async (w, eventArgs) =>
    {
        BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(eventArgs.BluetoothAddress);
        try
        {
            var SERVICEUUID = eventArgs.Advertisement.ServiceUuids.FirstOrDefault();
            var CHARACUUID = new Guid("00001809-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

            //FIXME: Getting invalid cast exception at this point
            var gatt = await device.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(SERVICEUUID);
            Debug.WriteLine($"{device.Name} Services: {gatt.Services.Count}, {gatt.Status}, {gatt.ProtocolError}");

            var characs = await gatt.Services.Single(s => s.Uuid == SERVICEUUID).GetCharacteristicsAsync();
            var charac = characs.Characteristics.Single(c => c.Uuid == CHARACUUID);

            //TODO: Parse temperature value to float
            var val = await charac.ReadValueAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error getting characteristics: " + e);
        }
    };
```

The exception I get is:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice' to type 'Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.IBluetoothLEDevice3' 
at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW_WinRT(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget)    
at Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(Guid serviceUuid)
```

The BluetoothLEDevice apparently implements the IBluetoothLEDevice3 interface, so I don't understand how it can't be casted. Any help on why this happens is much appreciated. My device is a Raspberry PI3 if that matters. Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

When debugging the code, I see that the BluetoothLEDevice's DeviceAccessInformation property throws the exception and it gets propagated to the top level:

> DeviceAccessInformation = 'device.DeviceAccessInformation' threw an
>   exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

**Update2**

When I try accessing GATT services directly this way, I get a different exception:

```
BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(eventArgs.BluetoothAddress);
            var gattService = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(device.DeviceId);
```

The exception in this case is

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file
>   specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at StempHub.StartupTask.<>c.<<-ctor>b__5_0>d.MoveNext()

Comment: What's your windows iot core version?

Comment: It's 10.0.14393.1066

Answer (score 0):

`GetGattServicesForUuidAsync()` api is newly introduced in v10.0.14965 but not implemented in this version and it is implemented in 15003, you can check [Windows 10 SDK Preview Build 14965 Released](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/11/21/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-14965-released/#eRujElP24KSQ2l14.97) and [Windows 10 SDK Preview Build 15003 Released](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/13/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-15003-released/#K55uxwAEdRla2Uff.97).

So you may need windows iot core version 15003 or higher.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try updating my OS over the weekend and see if it solves the issue.